# "Save error: Creation of layer failed" when saving selection as new layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, select, save

I have used Select (Features) to select features from a 2nd order administrative boundary layer: refer to image:

[image]

I want to save the features to a new layer:

[image]

but this is the error message that I receive:

[image]

How might I resolve this error:

> Export to vector file failed.
>
> Error: Creation of layer failed (OGR error: Failed to create file Assam and Mizoram.shp: Permission denied)

and save the selection to a new layer?

Comment: Try without whitespaces in the name

Comment: It worked! Thank you Taras and BERA for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have just typed in a file name without defining a save location. To save a file you need to click on the 'ellipsis' button <kbd>...</kbd> to the right of the 'File name' line edit.

This will open a 'Save layer as' dialog where you can specify a location to save your shapefile and enter the file name.

You should then see a full file path string in place of where you currently have "Assam and Mizoram".

[image]

An alternative way to save selected features is to use the ["Extract Selected Features"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#extract-selected-features) algorithm from the processing toolbox. This gives you a number of save options including saving to a location in your local file system, creating a temporary layer etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the exact path where you want to save the file and you must choose the correct file type.